# Elasticsearch 1.2.1 exception: Root type mapping not empty after parsing

Tags: java, exception, elasticsearch

After updating to Elasticsearch `1.2.1` I keep getting the following exception on the following mapping:

```
{
    "tags": {
        "properties": {
            "tags": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the exception:

```
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: Root type mapping not empty after parsing! Remaining fields: [tags : {properties={tags={index=not_analyzed, type=string}}}]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapperParser.parse(DocumentMapperParser.java:265)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapperParser.parseCompressed(DocumentMapperParser.java:189)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperService.parse(MapperService.java:387)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperService.merge(MapperService.java:253)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaDataCreateIndexService$2.execute(MetaDataCreateIndexService.java:363)
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

@Mark this appears to be a bug in 1.2.X. There have been multiple others that have reported similar issues, I'll link to the tickets below. Basically it appears that they tightened up on syntax for mappings in 1.2.X but they appear to have caused some problems with previously valid mappings. Yours is one example.

I'd suggest you open a bug report - more power in numbers. Happy to chime in saying "me too" if you open a ticket, as I've recreated the problem on 1.2.1 .

For now I've been able to the following to work which I believe gives you the same desired result:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/yourindexname -d 
'{
   "mappings":
   {
    "tags":
      {
       "properties":
         {
          "tags":
            {
             "type":"string",
             "index":"not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        }
    }
}'
```

Tickets:

https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/6414

https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/6304

https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/6415

Comment: When I try what you have suggested, I get "{"error":"IndexAlreadyExistsException[[indexName] already exists]","status":400}". Any idea?

Comment: @KartikeyaSinha you probably try to create a new index with an already existing name.

Answer (score 7):

This will help you

you will get want you want to do

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/new_index -d '
{
  "mappings": { 
    "tags": {
      "properties": {
        "tags": { 
           "type":"string",
           "index":"not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

or you can also do this way

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/new_index/new_index_type/_mappings -d '
{
  "new_index_type": {
    "properties": {
      "tags": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem because I had mappings with **same type** in the elastic `config/mappings` directory.
Removing the mapping file solded my problem.

Comment: This fixed it for me on 1.7 as well.  I had only one mapping in the config as above, but I was also setting the same one explicitly in the template parameter of the elasticsearch output in my logstash config.